# OpenGL ES 2.0: matrix multiplication problem

Tags: iphone, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to draw a quadrilateral using OpenGL ES 2.0.
My vertex shader looks like this:

```
uniform mat4 mvp;
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 colorVarying;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * position;
    colorVarying = color;
}
```

If I use these vertices:

```
-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.f, 1.f,
 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.f, 1.f,
-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.f, 1.f,
 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.f, 1.f
```

and this matrix (in column-major order, as are all following matrices):

```
0.5,0,0,0,
0,  1,0,0,
0,  0,1,0,
0.5,0,0,1
```

the quad covers the right half of the viewport. Indeed, if I multiply those two matrices I get the vertices

```
0,    -1,     0,     1,
1,    -1,     0,     1,
0,     1,     0,     1,
1 ,    1,     0,     1,
```

and if I use those vertices and an identity matrix, I get the same result. So it seems that the multiplication is done correctly.

Now, if I multiply these vertices (A):

```
-100.0f, -100.0f, 301.0f, 1.0f,
 100.0f, -100.0f, 301.0f, 1.0f,
-100.0f,  100.0f, 301.0f, 1.0f,
 100.0f,  100.0f, 301.0f, 1.0f,
```

by this matrix (M):

```
0.4170         0         0         0
     0    0.5560         0         0
     0         0   -1.2220   -1.0000
     0         0  444.4440         0
```

I get these vertices (B):

```
 0.2075,    0.2766,   -0.9892,    1.0000
-0.2075,    0.2766,   -0.9892,    1.0000,
 0.2075,   -0.2766,   -0.9892,    1.0000,
-0.2075,   -0.2766,   -0.9892,    1.0000,
```

and if I pass my shader the B vertices and an identity matrix, it renders a small rectangle in the middle of the viewport. But if I pass it the A vertices and the M matrix, it renders nothing.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that gl_Position after the vertex shader completes goes through clipping where it is compared against the range [-W W] and clipped ( not drawn ) if it gl_Position falls outside of that range.

IF you multiply A * M and set the result to gl_Position, then given the matrices you are using the W coordinate will be -301, a negative number, which will invert the clipping comparison.

Try multiplying the matrix M by -1 before doing the multiplication, that should yield the same results as multiplying matrix B by the identity matrix.

From the "[Red Book](http://glprogramming.com/red/appendixg.html)":

> Avoid using negative w vertex coordinates and negative q texture coordinates. OpenGL might not clip such coordinates correctly and might make interpolation errors when shading primitives defined by such coordinates.

Comment: Hmm... now I don't know which answer to accept. The solution turned out to be multiplying just the lower right quadrant by -1, not the entire matrix. However, you may be right in saying that the negative w was the problem. I thought it was the triangles being one-sided, but when I try to draw a single triangle, it gets drawn no matter in what order I list the vertices, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The math library you are using might not use the same matrix order as GLSL. Try transposing your matrix M before passing it to the shader.

Comment: I'm not using any math library. I put both the matrix and the vertices in column order. Also, if that had been the problem, the first attempt with the half-viewport rectangle would not have worked, either. Still, I gave transposing M a try, but it still did not display anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that with that -1 in the wz cell, the triangles ended up with their normal in the opposite directions, and since they are one-sided they were not drawn. I solved the problem by changing M to this:

```
0.4170         0         0         0
     0    0.5560         0         0
     0         0    1.2220    1.0000
     0         0 -444.4440         0
```

I also changed the sign of the z column (actually row since the matrix is transposed) in order to keep -1 as near and +1 as far on the z axis.